# Why does this test fail if someone else runs it at the same time?

Tags: c++, testing

I was watching a [conference talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5senBJUkPc) (No need to watch it to understand my question but if you're curious it's from 35m28s to 36m28s). The following test was shown:

```cpp
TEST(Foo, StorageTest){
  StorageServer* server = GetStorageServerHandle(); 
  auto my_val = rand();
  server -> Store("testKey", my_val); 
  EXPECT_EQ(my_val, server->Load("testKey")); 
}
```

1. One of the speakers said: "you can only expect that storing data to a production service works if only one copy of that test is running at a time."
2. The other speaker said: "Once you add continuous integration in the mix, the test starts failing". I don't know a lot about CI/CD.

I am having some trouble understanding both claims 1. and 2. Any help?

Comment: Think of `server` as representing anything that's not isolated by the test.  A SQL server, a public file, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One of the speakers said: "you can only expect that storing data to a production service works if only one copy of that test is running at a time."

Right. Imagine if two instances of this code are running. If both `Store` operations execute before either `Load` operation takes place, the one whose `Store` executed first will load the wrong value.

Consider this pattern where the two instances are called "first" and "second":

1. First `Store` executes, stores first random value.
2. Second `Store` starts executing, starts storing second random value.
3. First `Load` is blocked on the second `Store` completing due to a lock internal to the database
4. Second `Load` is blocked on the `Store` completing due to a local internal to the database.
5. Second `Store` finishes and release the internal lock.
6. First `Load` can now execute, it gets second random value.
7. `EXPECT_EQ` fails as the first and second random values are different.

> The other speaker said: "Once you add continuous integration in the mix, the test starts failing".

If a CI system is testing multiple instances of the code at the same time, race conditions like the example above can occur and cause tests to fail as the multiple instances race with each other.

Comment: What confuses me is that, for me, it's like launching "two programs", they are not in the same process ==> no shared memory ==> no race condition.

Comment: @PhilippeLafourcade As your question says, they're both storing data to the production service.

Comment: @PhilippeLafourcade Here's a [simulation](https://godbolt.org/z/cq1Yc8nbE)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh. Great. Thanks a lot \ (•◡•) /

Comment: @TedLyngmo Done !